# How to know when and which files are changed in windows filesystem with winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I make program with spyware features for education, and I need to know in the program when file system is changing file, and what file is being changed.

How can I do that in C++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Windows, look at [`SHChangeNotifyRegister()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120.aspx).  Not only does it tell you what kind of change occured, but it also tells you which exact file(s) were changed.

Comment: this work in window vista or seven? and how i can with this function get event when any file in filesystem or in some specific directory are changed?

Comment: The last parameter specifies the folder(s) you want to monitor. To monitor the entire filesystem, either create an entry for each local drive letter (skip mapped drive letters), or a single entry whose path is set to NULL (but then you will receive notifications from all shell objects, not just the local filesystem).

Answer (score 11):

You are probably looking for Win32 [Directory Change Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There is also a .NET API called the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) that exposes the same functionality.

The linked page gives a good example for subscribing to file system notifications. For more low-level access to filesystem changes you will have to look into [Change Journals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That API is vastly more complicated so the first, directory change notifications, is probably your best place to start.

For the sake of mentioning it, the Linux kernel has a subsystem for this called [inotifiy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Comment: Directory Change Notifications notify only when some file in whatched dir is created or removed. This is cool, Thanks! But i need some thing like this but for changing file content.

Comment: It also allows you to see file changes in that tree using the [`FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag. You will have to heed the warning regarding filesystem caching, however.