# Need Win32 API to watch FileSystem changes

Tags: winapi, filesystems

Can anyone suggest me the win32 api to watch file system changes..I know about the .Net class FileSystemWatcher, but my boss asked me to concentrate on win32 API.

Comment: Did you at least search anywhere first? A quick Google on `winapi directory changes` turned up [How to know when and which files are changed in windows filesystem with winapi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13744138/62576) right here at StackOverflow.

Comment: @KenWhite I was using this feature for more than a decade from C#, and spend more than a hour trying to find underlying Win32 calls. I sure know how to search, but C# terminology gets under way.

Answer (score 3):

[`FindFirstChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a simple API but does not give you any real information about what has changed. The better function to use is [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The better function to use is `SHChangeNotifyRegister`, which is the accepted answer in the link I posted above. (Not downvoting, but the duplicate was very easy to find.)

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan has mentioned the simple easy-to-use functions.

For real heavy lifting (you need to detect changes which occurred between runs of your program, etc) you can also look at the NTFS Change Journal.