# Wait for new data in a file

Tags: winapi

I wanna read file, while another process is writing it.
So my process reads a file till the end, but what is the correct and efficient way to wait for new data ?
Is there some specialized API for this ?

Found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986833/read-a-continuously-updated-file-and-wait-for-new-data-to-be-written-to-the-file) but for posix

Comment: Try `ReadDirectoryChangesW` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376688/need-win32-api-to-watch-filesystem-changes

Answer (score 1):

[I/O Completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) are designed for this. [PostQueuedCompletionStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/postqueuedcompletionstatus) can be used to notify worker threads of external events after associating the Io completion port with a specified file handle([CreateIoCompletionPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/createiocompletionport)).
[I/O Completion Ports also apply to Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports#supported-io-functions). There is [a sample for socket](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/iocp/server/IocpServer.Cpp#L247).